# ErrorAction SilentlyContinue Missing expression after unary operator

Tags: batch-file, powershell

What I want to do is to suppress the error/warning message and continue executing my batch script. So what I am doing is something like this:

```
SET psh_path="%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

%psh_path% -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" -Command "Test_invalid_command;"
```

But Its giving me error:

```
Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
```

One way I found to solve this is creating a `silentlyContinue.ps1` file with command

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
```

and then using Dot Sourcing like this:

```
%psh_path% -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command ". '.\silentlyContinue.ps1'; Test_invalid_command;"
```

My concern is how this can be acheived in first case, I mean passing option to -ErrorAction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-ErrorAction is not a parameter of Powershell.exe

Run powershell.exe /? for a list of it's parameters.

The -ErrorAction settings need to be included in your command script, either explicitly or sourced from another script as you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
SET psh_path="%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

%psh_path% -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command "Test_invalid_command" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```